# applying if-else condition on 4 arrays containing 19 matrices of dim 50*50

Tags: r, arrays, if-statement, conditional-statements, subscript

I have 4 50*50 matrices and I want to use if-else to get 4 sets of binary matrices. Now I if I want to apply a sequence of thresholds then am having problem.

Please see the following code:

```
X <- mvrnorm(n=50, mu = rep(0, 50), Sigma = matrix(1,50,50)+diag(50))
p1<- nrow(X)
threshold <- seq(from = 5, to = 95, by = 5)

array1<-array(0,c(p1,p1,length(threshold)))
array2<-array(0,c(p1,p1,length(threshold)))
array3<-array(0,c(p1,p1,length(threshold)))
array4<-array(0,c(p1,p1,length(threshold)))

criteria1 <- t(X)%*%X
criteria2 <- t(X)+X
criteria3 <- sqrt(t(X)%*%X)
criteria4 <- (t(X)+X)/2

for (i in 1:length(threshold)) {
  array1[,,i] <- ifelse( criteria1 <threshold[i],0,1)
  array2[,,i] <- ifelse( criteria2 <threshold[i],0,1)
  array3[,,i] <- ifelse( criteria3 <threshold[i],0,1)
  array4[,,i] <- ifelse( criteria4 <threshold[i],0,1)
}

Error in array4[, , i] <- ifelse(criteria2 < threshold[i], 0, 1) : 
  incorrect number of subscripts
```

Comment: Can you show he object `p1` as it is returning error

Comment: it is the nrow(X)

Comment: Is your `my.mat1` same as `array1`?  In that case, the code is working fine for me

Comment: yes. am sorry. I changed it on my code.

Comment: Your code is not showing any error for me.  Try your code on a fresh R session

Comment: From which package are you using `mvrnorm` from?